# How to uninstall an anti malware installed in windows using ubuntu OS?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Hope someone can help me with this. It's like this, my husband trying to be an IT, basically he's not and honestly I'm not too, installed MBAM anti malware to his Windows PC. It's the anti malware his company is using. Because of whatever reason he has, he installed it. After installing and running a PC scan, he can't open his PC because it's asking a license key. Thanks God his PC is in dual boot. He installed Ubuntu a month ago. All his CAD files are in windows and he needs a revision of his project he is working on.  Can he uninstall MBAM installed in windows using ubuntu? or any other way he can use XP again? Need help on this.

Thank u..

Comment: I thought this was software to prevent unauthorized use of the system, not antimalware.  If so, then it's like encrypting your hard drive and forgetting the password/key.  Basically, you're out of luck.  If it could easily be bypassed, the software would be worthless.  Unless his company can help, he may be screwed royally.

Comment: He can use linux to locate the MBAM files on windows C drive in the Programs folder and delete it from there. This can break the app and you can clean up after you boot-up.

Answer (score 0):

First, he should copy all of his documents, pictures, etc., to a safe place, because you might end up re-installing XP to use those files in his computer or on another computer at work. This should be pretty easy using Ubuntu and a USB drive large enough to hold the files.

Second, I doubt there is any way to remove an installed program on the Windows side of a dual-boot system using Linux. There are registry edits you'd need to do at the very least. Ask someone who's tried to uninstall Norton from XP from inside XP!

Comment: I think so too. Maybe I'll have him uninstall windows xp and install it again or try first suggestions by @mango, whichever works.

Comment: If I remember correctly, installing XP after any other OS will not work, as XP will install its bootloader over the top of grub, and you won't be able to boot to Ubuntu. If you want to dual-boot, I believe you'll have to re-install XP, then re-install grub so you can choose between Ubuntu and XP. Do some research before you begin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this particular product, but you could always try booting Windows XP in safe mode, then uninstalling the product. As for your Ubuntu method, this is a no go because Ubuntu can't run windows software without wine, and wine breaks native installations. At best you could theoretically use Ubuntu to delete enough of the program to disable it, allowing you to boot in and uninstall it, but that's risky and could just as easily make things worse. I would try booting XP in safe mode, and uninstalling the program.

## Steps:

[You will need to remove the `#` from the http#s:// in the screenshot links before putting them into your web browser.]

1. Turn on the computer, press F8, boot up Windows XP in safe mode, and login as you normally would. When logging in make sure to choose a user account that has priviledges to install/remove software.

   screenshot1: https://copy.com/F97cpZX01US9

   screenshot2: https://copy.com/jYi0QPEYWwWT

   screenshot3: http#s://copy.com/gmi8TJGRYAWg

   screenshot4: http#s://copy.com/vFVFtzPX8QUZ
2. Open the start menu, open control panel, open add and remove programs, and then uninstall the desired application.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have him try this when he woke up. He's in Middle east and I'm in Phils, a 5-hour difference in time. I'll update soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it

1) Boot into windows xp in safe mode(invoked by Function keys like F8 based on your pc) and uninstall it.

2) Boot into Ubuntu and delete every file of MBAM anti malware software from windows xp drive, installed files will be in 'c:\program files' you can delete that.

Neither of the above two won't cause any problem to windows xp, but its better if you have important files in windows xp drive back them up first.

First try the first method its prefered, if it wont work then second.